# .htaccess Vanity/Nice URLs Causing 404 Error to be Homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument, vanity-url

I recently switched from using this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^example index.php?page=example [L]
```

To this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The issue is that if I visit something like example.com/euffhfrfreif - it'll just display me my homepage.

I'm trying to configure vanity URLs, so that rather than visitors using example.com/index.php?page=contact, they'll just visit example.com/contact - I've seen this a lot online and it's supposed to be better for Google, etc.

This error doesn't apply to any folders, so visiting example.com/djfhds/fdjdnf will display a 404 error.

How can I get my 404 error back but keep (or keep something similar too) my new system?

Also: I have rewriteengine on and a 404 error page defined in .htaccess.

Comment: Your current rule is rewriting to `index.php?page=` for every request that doesn't contain a `/` and `.` and is not a directory. You cannot get a regular 404 page with this rule. You will have to think properly why do you need this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following rules. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The issue is that you are using an else statement in index.php to show your homepage.

Change your else statement to a 404 error page and make your home page be at `index.php?page=home`, then add this to htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227633/discussion-between-jacobsa-and-ravindersingh13).